# Generate two XML files using PHP

Tags: php, xml

I currently use the following PHP code to generate an XML file from form inputs on a HTML page (I'm using `$_POST`):

```html
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$doc->formatOutput = true;
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = true;
$doc->loadXML($xml->asXML(), LIBXML_NOBLANKS);
$doc->save('../application/'.$filefname.$filesname.'_'.date("Y-m-d").'.xml');
```

However I would like to generate two XML files, each with different information.  Do I need to do something like have two variables? eg. `$xml1` and `$xml2`, `$doc1` and `$doc2` like so?

```html
$doc1 = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$doc1->formatOutput = true;
$doc1->preserveWhiteSpace = true;
$doc1->loadXML($xml1->asXML(), LIBXML_NOBLANKS);
$doc1->save('../application/'.$filefname.$filesname.'_'.date("Y-m-d").'.xml');

$doc2 = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$doc2->formatOutput = true;
$doc2->preserveWhiteSpace = true;
$doc2->loadXML($xml2->asXML(), LIBXML_NOBLANKS);
$doc2->save('../application/'.$filefname.$filesname.'_'.date("Y-m-d").'.xml');
```

Eg. Two email addresses and two names are entered into the online form, I want each person's details in a seperate file.
Customer 1's name and email in `cust1.xml` and Customer 2's name and email in `cust2.xml`

Comment: just run save twice with the 2 filenames

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reuse the `$doc` variable. As soon as you assign it a new `DOMDocument` the `$doc` variable points to the new instance.

```
// $doc points to instance #1 of DOMDocument
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0'); 

...

// $doc points to instance #2 of DOMDocument
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0');
```

The same applies to all reference types like objects.

Instead of duplicating your code you should create a function

```
function createDocument($xml) {
    $doc = new DOMDocument('1.0');
    $doc->formatOutput = true;
    $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = true;
    $doc->loadXML($xml->asXML(), LIBXML_NOBLANKS);
    $doc->save('../application/'.$filefname.$filesname.'_'.date("Y-m-d").'.xml');
}
```

You should always avoid code duplication. See [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) principle.

Comment: The two XML files will contain different information. So I don't want just a duplicate. Sorry if this wasn't clear. I edited my question.

Comment: If you want two different XML files, make the `createDocument` suggested here return the `$doc` instead of saving it, and save the returned document outside the function. e.g. `$doc1 = createDocument($xml1); $doc1->save(...)` (changed the answer to reflect this)

Comment: @RogierSpieker could you update the code just to give me an idea? Thanks - sorry I'm still learning as I go along.

Comment: @Jason done ;-) (will become visible after it is peer reviewed)